# WPF: How to Statically Initialize a List of CheckBoxes?

Tags: wpf, list, checkbox, listbox, observablecollection

How do I statically initialize a list of CheckBoxes? I can't quite get the initializers right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in XAML, create a ListBox that contains a CheckBox. Bind desired elements.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Pets" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Click="Pets_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Finally, use initializers to create a list of CheckBoxes.

```
Pets.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CheckBox>()
    {
        { new CheckBox() {Content = "Cat", IsChecked = true} },
        { new CheckBox() {Content = "Dog", IsChecked = true} },
        { new CheckBox() {Content = "Goldfish", IsChecked = false} },
    };
```